# Latex PDF - Hyperref Zoom in - pdfview

Tags: tikz-pgf, hyperref, pdf

I am currently strugelling with the following problem:

I would like to create a TikZ graph in which I can click on the node text (hyperref) to jump and zoom in to another part of the graph:

[image]

I thought about

```
\begingroup
\hypersetup{pdfview={XYZ ?? ?? ??}}
\hyperlink{hello}{Reference}
\endgroup
```

what kicks in the problem of knowing the exact PDF coordinats and zoom factor for the node. (Can TikZ provide that?)

Do you know any solution for that?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: Would you please post the code you used to generate the shown graphic?